# ComboBox not showing SelectedValue after binding to Datatable

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I am binding a datatable from an SQL connection to a combo box and have a DisplayMember and ValueMember.

The current code is:

```
    Private Sub frmEditEmployees_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    cmbOffice.ValueMember = "intOffice"
    cmbOffice.DisplayMember = "strOffice"
    cmbOffice.DataSource = Nothing
    cmbOffice.DataSource = RunSQL("Select intOfficeID, strOffice from [Database].[dbo].[Table]", "Users").Tables(0)

    LoadEmployees(chkEx.Checked)

    End Sub
```

The SQL query runs correctly and returns the following when run:

intOfficeID|strOffice

1 | London

2 | Bristol

When the form loads the 2 options can be seen and selected in the drop down combo box.

However when I then try to reference the combobox I don't get any data from the properties. I get the following messages from the debug/immediate window.

```
?Me.cmbOffice.SelectedValue

{System.Data.DataRowView}
System.Data.DataRowView: {System.Data.DataRowView}
```

However when I select the different options in the combobox and question the index it does recognise the change.

```
?Me.cmbOffice.SelectedIndex
0
?Me.cmbOffice.SelectedIndex
1
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `Me.cmbOffice.SelectedValue` will of type of `intOffice` column, which in your sample are not loaded with sql query (`intOfficeID` loaded instead).

Comment: Fallen flat by a damn typo. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Still, if intOfficeID is of type `int`, then you should be able to get selected value `Dim selectedId = DirectCast(Me.cmbOffice.SelectedValue, Integer)`